# How are python inheritance rules different with that of java?

Tags: python, class, inheritance

I'm studying python now, but I'm having big problem in Class and Inheritance.
I'm really familiar with Java but python is very different from Java.
Belows are my test code :

```
class Chart(object):
  def __init__(self):
    pass

  def testMethod(self, a):
    print("a")


class MelonChart(Chart):
  def __init__(self):
    pass

  def testMethod(self, c):
    print("C")
    print("d")

  def testMethod(self, e, f):
    print("e")
    print("f")


chart = MelonChart()
chart.testMethod("a")
```

But it doesn't work.. and I don't know why..

Additionally, If both classes have 'init', and When I create instance of MelonChart, only MelonChart 'init' is called.

As a previous Java Programmer, I can not understand why constructor of parent doesn't have to be called...

If only 'Chart' class has 'init', and when I create instance of MelonChart, only parent's 'init' is called.

I don't know why,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it is the way Python is designed!

So you have learned one object language (Java) and are learning another one Python. The basics will more or less be the same at architecture level: you start by high level functionnalities and identify hierarchies of classes and objects.

But then, not only the syntax is different (indentation of Python is a delight for beginners...) but the implementation concepts are different:

- Java variables are bound to a type, Python's ones can refer to object of different types (at different times)
- Java does not support multiple inheritance and makes heavy usage of interface, Python accepts multiple inheritance and has no notion of interface
- Java accepts overloading of methods (same method with different signature), Python does not but has default values for last arguments, and keyword arguments
- Java call constructors for parent classes. Python has *special methods* (`__new__` and `__init__`) and implicitely calls them only once at object creation: the programmer has to explicitely calls `BaseClass.__init__(self)` if it is needed

TL/DR: do not try to reproduct Java idioms in Python but learn it as a different language.

Answer (score 0):

I think that error message is pretty straightforward:

> TypeError: testMethod() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given)

Python does not support method overloading

Answer (score -1):

In python, behind the scenes classes and objects are represented by dictionaries, and when you assign a new value to a key in a dictionary, it overwrites the old value in the dictionary.

It turns out, when you write:

```
def testMethod(self, c):
```

that creates an entry in a dictionary whose key is `testMethod` and whose value is a function object with 2 args.

Then when you write:

```
def testMethod(self, e, f):
```

that assigns a different value to the key `testMethod`, namely a function object with 3 args.

Then when you write:

```
chart.testMethod("a")
```

the `testMethod` key is looked up in the class dictionary, and the value is a function object that takes 3 args.

> Additionally, If both classes have 'init', and When I create instance
>   of MelonChart, only MelonChart 'init' is called.

Yep, the child class's `__init__()` method overrides the parent class's `__init__()` method--just like the `greet()` method does in the following code:

```
import java.io.*;

class Animal {
    public void greet(String greeting) {
        System.out.print("An Animal wishes you: ");
        System.out.println(greeting);
    }
}

class Dog extends Animal {
    public void greet(String greeting) {
        System.out.print("A Dog barks out: ");
        System.out.println(greeting);
    }
}

public class MyProg {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Dog d = new Dog();
        d.greet("hello");
    }
}

--output:--
A Dog barks out: hello
```

Isn't it weird that Java has different rules(and syntax) for methods that are constructors?

> If only 'Chart' class has 'init', and when I create instance of
>   MelonChart, only parent's 'init' is called.

That's how inheritance works: when the method isn't found in the base class, python goes up the inheritance chain looking for an `__init__()` method in the parent classes.

> As a previous Java Programmer, I can not understand why constructor of
>   parent doesn't have to be called...

In python, if your child class defines an `__init__()` method, then you have to manually call the parent class's constructor:

```
super().__init__()
```

Here's an example:

```
class Chart(object):
  def __init__(self, x):
    self.x = x

  def testMethod(self, a):
    print("a")


class MelonChart(Chart):
  def __init__(self, x, y):
    super().__init__(x)
    self.y = y


chart = MelonChart(10, 20)
print(chart.x, chart.y)

--output:--
10 20
```

Hey, look at that: no unseen, secret method calls to parent class constructors!  What is Java afraid of?  Come out into the light.  Let's be explicit instead of implicit, aite?

Finally, python indenting is 4 spaces, not 2 spaces, not 5 spaces.  It's 4 spaces.  You can use any indenting you want, but if you are going to post on a public form, then it's 4 spaces.  Mandatory.

Comment: "In python, behind the scenes classes and objects are dictionaries" - no they're not. Most of their attributes are tracked using dicts, but classes aren't dicts, and the only objects that are dicts are the instances of the `dict` type.

Answer (score -2):

Python is much more flexible than Java. If you know what you're doing, it gives you more freedom, but does not hold your hand the way Java does.

Read [Learn Python the Hard Way](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex44.html) to learn more about inheritance.

In Python if you declare the same method in a class twice, the first one gets overwritten, so your first method in `MelonChart` will never get called.

Regarding the `__init__` you have to call parent's init like so:

```
class Child(Parent):
    super(Child, self).__init__()
```